# Facebook Login Dialog permission for deselect pages and group

Tags: facebook, api, graph, facebook-login

I am using Facebook Login dialog. here is doc https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/overview/ 
Here is example: 
[image: Facebook login dialog]

By Default Facebook automatic select all group and pages. i want, it will be deselect all group and page list.so that user can choose page or group manually.

is there any available graph API scope parameter for solve this issue.

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no parameter for that.

You can not influence this particular behavior of the login dialog.

(The user can clear them all in one go by using the icon on top of the list.)